# jquery too much recursion error on form.each function with bootstrap validation

Tags: jquery, recursion, bootstrapvalidator

There was no console error for my form that uses Bootstrap Validator (http://formvalidation.io/) until I needed to put multiple forms on the page.  Now, when I run $(form).each(), I'm getting a too much recursion error.

```
    $('form').each(function(){
        var form_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            fields: {
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                        }
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }).on('success.form.bv', app.form_handler);
    });
```

Here's the javascript app.form_handler:

```
app.form_handler = function( evt ){
    evt.preventDefault();
    app.$ajax_form = $(evt.target);
    var serialized_data = app.$ajax_form.serialize();
    app.post_ajax( serialized_data );
};
```

Then the post_ajax function...

```
 app.post_ajax = function( serial_data ){
    var post_data = { 
        action     : 'cm_ajax',
        nonce      : cm_ajax.nonce,
        serialized : serial_data,
    };

    $.post( cm_ajax.ajax_url, post_data, app.ajax_response, 'json' )
};
```

Comment: Not sure what `app.form_handler` does (is that PHP?).  But the code you've provided handles the same event `success.form.bv` each time *any* form is validated - so form1 raises `succes.form.bv` which `app.form_handler` then initiates validation on form2 which raises the same event which validates form1, which raises the event and validates form2 etc... In your `app.form_handler` code, try checking `$(e.target)` which should give you the specific form which has just been validated and limit the code (more info: http://formvalidation.io/settings/#event-form)

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  The app.form_handler is javascript -- I'll update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Too Much Recursion Error issue` might happen if there is a form that doesn't follow Bootstrap form structure.
See the [Writing form](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/#writing-form) section.

Meanwhile, `$(form)` actually will choose ALL forms in the page.
So, either checking ALL forms on page to ensure that ALL of them use a standard Bootstrap form markup, or uses more strict selector such as `$('#form1, #form2')`

Answer (score 0):

This was triggering an error because I was logged in to WordPress as an admin (meaning lots of hidden forms were on the page).  Thus, the $(form).each function was running on every form, which didn't use standard Bootstrap markup, triggering the error.

I fixed this by adding a custom class to the forms I wanted the validator to run on, then added an IF clause to only run the validator if($(this).hasClass('bootstrapFormClass')){ ... }

This worked fine and now the validator, and all my forms work fine.